# Cofinality of $\alpha$ is a cardinal and $\text{cf}(\aleph_1)$

Tags: set-theory

I need to prove that for any $\alpha$, $\text{cf}(\alpha)$ is a cardinal. I've seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137581/why-cofinality-is-a-cardinal) post and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594418/why-is-cf%ce%b1-a-cardinal-for-any-limit-ordinal-%ce%b1?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I do not understand their solutions.

The hint I've been given is: Given $j:\lambda\to\text{cf}(\alpha)$ a bijection, construct a cofinal function $h:\lambda\to\alpha$ by recursion, such that for each $\iota<\text{cf}(\alpha)$, if $\kappa=j^{-1}(\iota)$, then $f(j(\kappa))\leq h(\kappa)$.

I would like to know how to use this hint to solve the problem, and how it relates to the posts I've mentioned, since they talk about constructing a cofinal sequence instead of a cofinal function, which is the definition I've been given of cofinality. Also, what does it mean to prove that a set is a cardinal? Does it suffice to prove that it is an initial ordinal?

Also, I need to prove $\text{cf}(\aleph_1)=\aleph_1$; I believe it is because the union of countably many countable sets is countable, but I don't understand why at all.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Your hint doesn't say what $f$ is (though I assume from context it is some arbitrary cofinal function $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\to \alpha$). What is the definition you are using for cofinal function and cofinality?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. A function $f:\alpha\to \beta$ is cofinal if for each $\gamma<\beta$ there is some $\delta<\alpha$ such that $\gamma<f(\alpha)$ (this is what the problem says, but I think it should be $f(\delta)$ instead of $f(\alpha)$ at the end).

$\alpha$ is the cofinality of $\beta$ if $\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that there is a cofinal function from $\alpha$ to $\beta$.

Comment: Yes, should be $f(\delta)$ certainly. In that case, I think the hint is a little overcomplicated. If $j:\lambda\to \operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ is a bijection, then $f\circ j$ is a cofinal function $\lambda \to \alpha.$ So $\lambda\ge \operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ by definition of cofinality. Therefore $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ is an initial ordinal (and yes, that's the same thing as a cardinal in this context).

Comment: I understand what $f$ is (the cofinal function given by the definition of $\text{cf}(\alpha)$), and I get why $\lambda\geq\text{cf}(\alpha)$ implies that $\text{cf}(\alpha)$ is an initial ordinal. Now, why is $f\circ j$ cofinal? Also, no definition by recursion is needed, right? Sorry, I have many gaps in this topic.

Comment: The definition says that a function is cofinal if its range is unbounded in $\alpha,$ but since $j$ is a bijection the range of $f\circ j$ is the same as the range of $f.$ I think the recursive construction in the hint is intended to be an *increasing* cofinal function, which is sometimes part of the definition, but apparently isn't here... which is why I say the hinted solution is overcomplicated.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much. Now, any hints on how to prove $\text{cf}(\aleph_1)=\aleph_1$?

Comment: Wrote an answer that includes a hint on that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, given the definitions, the solution is actually less complicated than the hint suggests. If $f:\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\to \alpha$ is cofinal, and $j:\lambda\to \operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ is a bijection, then $f\circ j$ is a cofinal function $\lambda \to \alpha,$ since it has the same range as $f.$

For showing $\aleph_1$ is regular, observe that for any countable ordinal $\alpha,$ and $f:\alpha\to \omega_1,$ the range of $f$ is countable. If you can show the range is bounded by a countable ordinal, this shows $f$ is not cofinal, and you're done. As you suggest, the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable is pertinent.